# Dynamic formsets in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model with booleanfield:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = ...
    field2 = ...
    default = models.BooleanField(...)
```

How can change admin fieldsets in respect to default value? e. g. when default is True field2 should appear in fieldsets and when not it should not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I think i can check it in form init and set unneeded field to None